# Cannot understand this Js code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to NodeJs, had experience in Java and Angular Typescript.

Some one has written this code that I am not able to understand, Can you please help me out ?, I tried printing output on the console but I am not able to grasp the syntax.

```
function toMap(arr, key) {
  var map = {};
  console.log("Key is"+ key);
  if (arr) {
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
      map[arr[i][key]] = arr[i];
    }
  }

  return map;
}
```

The arr is an array of objects that is coming from the database and the id is a key and the value passed here is 'id'.

Comment: what does `arr` look like ... what does the returned object look like - seeing those two should make it clear what the function does - if not, I'm not sure any amount of explanation could help

Comment: its is a key value pair object  comming from the db

Comment: so, way too complicated to add to the question?

Comment: its added if you check i hope

Comment: never mind - people have answered

Comment: thanks new to js and node give me some time @JaromandaX

Answer (score 0):

this function is simply converting array into required format of key value pair, nothing more than this, if you want to understand nodeJs properly, make sure you are aware of what are callbacks? and how its used in nodeJS ?,
**"arr"** having the multiple values, for loop is make all values in single object with common key  `map[arr[i][key]] = arr[i];` , `map` is final array which will return from this function.
you are calling this function `toMap(arr, key)`  by sending the two parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it takes a collection of objects like

```
[{ omg:'ahh' }, {omg:'ohnoes'}]
```

and turns it into something like this:

```
{
  'ahh': {omg:'ahh'},
  'ohnoes': {omg: 'ohnoes'}
}
```

Using the call `toMap([{ omg:'ahh' }, {omg:'ohnoes'}], 'omg')`. It seems very similar to the [keyBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#keyBy) function in lodash.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. `arr` parameter is an array of objects (same, possibly some sort of records), `key` is a string representing property existing in those objects. 
Function simply returns a new associative object where each of those objects is accessible by value available at `key` property.

Example:

```
people = [ { name: 'John', age: 20 }, 
           { name: 'Alice', age: 32 }, 
           { name: 'Bartek', age: 24 } 
         ]

map = toMap(people, 'name')
```

and now map is equal to:

```
{
    'John': { name: 'John', age: 20 },
    'Alice': { name: 'Alice', age: 32 },
    'Bartek': { name: 'Bartek', age: 24 },
}
```

Comment: yes this is it is there any simple way of doing it i am not able to grasp the syntax